# Flex 4 - Set focus to none

Tags: focus, flash-builder, flex4.6, setfocus

I'm building an Away3d application which uses Flex 4.6 for UI. The arrow keys are required to move the 3d components - however, after using a component such as a slider, the application gives it focus, which means the arrow keys control it.

I can't find any way to set the global application focus to nothing - is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried setting the application's focusManager.setFocus(new Button()), and null (which crashes it), I'm sure it's easy but I can only find advice on how to set the focus to a component, not set it to nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's been a while since I've used flex, but can you listen for a mouseup event on the slider then force the focus back to the 3d component with something like focusManager.setFocus(3dcomponent);

Comment: Actually, I'd not thought of doing that - I've not got the 3dView as a component in itself, but will try with that, or in any case use a hidden, empty UIComponent. If you want to put this as an answer, if it works I'll choose it - won't get to tonight but will def look tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try listening for a mouseup event on the slider then force the focus back to the 3d component with something like:

```
focusManager.setFocus(3dcomponent);
```

Comment: Got a chance to look - I put a hidden component in the root application and set focus to this when a click is detected on the 3d view, works a charm, thanks!